# Failed to resolve dependencies: resources:1.2.14

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am facing this issue with Grails v2.2.0

*Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.14*

- grails clean
- grails install-plugin resources*
- grails list-plugins
  ... 
  .. basically **ALL** grails commands I am trying to run are failing with the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this:

```
mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
mavenCentral()
```

in you BuildConfig.groovy file inside the repositories brackets

(by the way which version of grails are you using?)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding inside your BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
  runtime ':resources:1.2.14'
}
```